# C | Handling multiple arguments in macro function

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to make a function similar to `printf()`, I want it to take multiple arguments so that I can use them when printing, roughly like the following:

```c
void PRINT_RED(string, ...) {
  fprintf(stderr, "\033[91m");
  fprintf(stderr, "%s", string, __va_arg_pack());
  fprintf(stderr, "\033[0m");
}
```

Take in consideration that I want it to have the following example API `PRINT_RED("%s %s %d", string1, string2, int1);`.

But as a macro, so I tried:

```c
#define PRINT_RED(string, ...) \
  fprintf(stderr, "\033[91m"); \
  fprintf(stderr, "%s", string, __va_arg_pack()); \
  fprintf(stderr, "\033[0m");
```

And apparently `__va_arg_pack()` can only be defined in inline functions... Can anybody guide me on how to handle multiple arguments in a macro function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the macro `__VA_ARGS__`, which translates to the variable arguments passed to a macro.

```
#define PRINT_RED(string, ...) \
  fprintf(stderr, "\033[91m"); \
  fprintf(stderr, "%s", string, __VA_ARGS__); \
  fprintf(stderr, "\033[0m");
```